# How do you convert UISegmentedControl type to int for calculation?

Tags: user-interface, swift, operators, uisegmentedcontrol

New to swift programming. I am creating an application to do calculations for the user with a simple UI interface. After I receive input from UITextfield (var weight), I would like to divide that value from the input given from UISegmentedControl. How can I take the value given from UISegmentedControl and convert it to an int so that it may be divided from var weight.. Here is my code

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var weight: UITextField!


@IBOutlet weak var reps: UISegmentedControl!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func Calculate(sender: UIButton) {


    NSLog("Weight = \(weight.text)")

    NSLog("reps = \(reps.selectedSegmentIndex)")

}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the value of the selected UISegmentedControl, you can do something like that:

```
var myInt:Int = reps.titleForSegmentAtIndex(reps.selectedSegmentIndex)!.toInt()!
```

**BUT** I'd highly recommend you to use double, as your choice of type, because int isn't that great for calculations. So you would have to cast your string into a double:

```
var myRepsDouble = (reps.titleForSegmentAtIndex(reps.selectedSegmentIndex)! as NSString).doubleValue
```

Also if you want to calculate with the value of the UITextField, you also have to cast it to double, because you can't calculate with Strings:

```
var myTextFieldDouble = (weight.text as NSString).doubleValue
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Much respect for developers like yourself!

Comment: You are welcome. Could you please accept my answer that other people can find the answer easier?

Comment: Hello! I have casted the weight variable from UITextField to type double using your last suggestion. How would i now use that value to perform a calculation. Say I want to divide var weight by two and NSLog the result?

Comment: do something like that: `var result = myTextFieldDouble / 2`

Comment: Sorry to say that and don't get me wrong: I like to help. But you should try to solve some problems by yourself. Otherwise you won't get better at programming. It's okay to ask some questions, but try to do something yourself. You can also do some basic-tutorials. For example on http://raywenderlich.com.

Comment: Didnt even see your reply until now. I just get frustrated sometimes and feel like all i need is help. Actually got it all figured out and finished my app minutes after I asked that. Thanks for your help..